# R code to 'tidy' the values of a discrete variable

Tags: r

Consider this data:

```
set.seed(200914)
y <- round(runif(20, 5, 15))
y
table(y)
```

In the real application y is a categorical variable such as "outcome code". I want to recode R so that its values are 1:n, while preserving order (Sometimes the variable may be ordinal.)

One answer is:

```
(ya <- y - min(y) + 1)
table(ya)
```

But this solution does not have minimal range which may make subsequent code inefficient. Trying again...

```
(suy <- sort(unique(y)))
(n <- length(suy))
yb <- y
for (i in 1:n) yb[which(y == suy[i])] <- i
table(yb)
```

yb is exactly what I want, but I wonder if I am computing it in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
yc <- as.numeric(factor(y))

table(yc)
#yc
#1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
#1 4 1 1 6 3 3 1
```

since essentially what you're looking for are the factor codes (I think).

Comment: +1  Infact I tried the factor method first, but for some reason I didn't post.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 yc <- match(y, sort(unique(y)))
 table(yc)

 #1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
 #1 4 1 1 6 3 3 1 

 all.equal(yb,yc)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Another option might be `findInterval`

```
 table(findInterval(y, sort( unique(y))))
 #1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
 #1 4 1 1 6 3 3 1
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(25)
y <- sample(1:20, 1e6,replace=TRUE)

f1 <- function() {suy <- sort(unique(y))
             n <- length(suy)
             yb <- y
             for (i in 1:n) yb[which(y == suy[i])] <- i
             table(yb)}

f2 <- function() {yc <- as.numeric(factor(y))
              table(yc)}


f3 <- function() {yd <- match(y, sort(unique(y)))
              table(yd)}

f4 <- function() {ye <- findInterval(y, sort(unique(y)))
              table(ye)}


library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), unit="relative", times=25L) 
#   Unit: relative
# expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# f1() 1.198901 1.208551 1.235237 1.242697 1.600400    25
# f2() 3.745317 3.593736 3.593330 3.596990 3.488292    25
# f3() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    25
# f4() 1.017857 1.038056 1.047112 1.038731 1.014825    25
```

Comment: Have you tried the second?  `findInterval` is generally faster.  Perhaps, the `sort` is making it slower.  One way would be to use `sort.int` and option `method="quick"`

Comment: Looks like the OP is a new SO user, so it might be good to mention that your answers are vectorized.